# Extracting XML data in Snowflake

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table TEST_XML that has a variant column SRC_XML that contains the following XML. When I try to extract QUESTION_TEXT and ANSWER_TEXT, am getting NULL as result, even though the XML has values in corresponding fields

```
<DATA_EXPORT>
  <HEADER>
    <ENTRY_DATE>
      <START>2021-04-02</START>
      <END>2021-04-02</END>
    </ENTRY_DATE>
    <QUESTION_COUNT>225</QUESTION_COUNT>
    <SURVEY_QUESTIONS>
      <QUESTION>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <QUESTION_TEXT>DO YOU TRAVEL?</QUESTION_TEXT>
        <ANSWER_TEXT>NO</ANSWER_TEXT>
      </QUESTION>
      <QUESTION>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <QUESTION_TEXT>HOW MANY LANGUAGES DO YOU SPEAK?</QUESTION_TEXT>
        <ANSWER_TEXT>6</ANSWER_TEXT>
      </QUESTION>
    </SURVEY_QUESTIONS>
  </HEADER>
</DATA_EXPORT>
```

The query that I used for extracting the data -

```
SELECT 
  XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'QUESTION') AS Q
, GET(XMLGET(Q, 'NUMBER'), '$') AS QUESTION_NUMBER
, GET(XMLGET(Q, 'QUESTION_TEXT'), '$') AS QUESTION
, GET(XMLGET(Q, 'ANSWER_TEXT'), '$') AS ANSWER
FROM TEST_XML,
LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(SRC_XML, 'HEADER', 0),'SURVEY_QUESTIONS'), '$'))D;
```

The output that I am expecting is

| QUESTION_NUMBER | QUESTION | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DO YOU TRAVEL? | NO |
| 2 | HOW MANY LANGUAGUES DO YOU SPEAK? | 6 |

What should i change in my query? Please advise.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - Am still getting NULL values on all the rows and columns. Could you please help with the query?

Comment: Please apologize. I did not understand how it worked, especially with LATERAL join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so getting your SQL that you put into the FLATTEN and pull those apart we see

```
  SELECT 
    XMLGET(SRC_XML, 'HEADER', 0) as h
    ,XMLGET(h,'SURVEY_QUESTIONS') as sq
   ,GET(sq, '$') as parts
   ,d.*
  FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(SRC_XML, 'HEADER', 0),'SURVEY_QUESTIONS'), '$'))D;
```

that your h sq and parts are all correct. But your questions which you called `q` is what the actual block is, so you don't need to pull that apart.

thus what you wanted to use was:

```
SELECT 
    GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'NUMBER'), '$') AS QUESTION_NUMBER
    , GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'QUESTION_TEXT'), '$') AS QUESTION
    , GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'ANSWER_TEXT'), '$') AS ANSWER
FROM TEST_XML,
LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(SRC_XML, 'HEADER', 0),'SURVEY_QUESTIONS'), '$'))D;
```

which gives:

```
QUESTION_NUMBER QUESTION                      ANSWER
1        "DO YOU TRAVEL?"                     "NO"
2        "HOW MANY LANGUAGES DO YOU SPEAK?"    6
```

Comment: You are amazing ! I was anticipating that you would help and you answered it well. Your solution worked. Thank you so much :) I understand $ gets the content of a particular tag and @ gets the tag name. How does LATERAL FLATTEN work? I went through the documentation, but I get confused when I encounter with a complex XML hierarchal structure. Could you please help me understand?

Comment: @vvazza FLATTEN takes something like an array, and makes a new row of data with the sub-object from the "array" plus some other meta-values, which can help you depending on the task you are doing. So in your data you are looping across `HEADER,SURVEY_QUESTIONS` which gives you each question as a row of SQL output, thus you can access anything from  `TEST_XML` and anything from current item of `D`. Basically FLATTEN is the same as `FOREACH` in Javascript or C#

Comment: Thank you ! I think I have started to understand and how to look through data from the answers you gave to two of my questions here. Will get back if i get any more questions :) Thanks, once again